# Kolmogorov: Definition of Experimental Data?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In [Foundations of the Theory of Probability](https://archive.org/details/foundationsofthe00kolm), Kolmogrov states:

> S2. The Relation to Experimental Data : "There is assumed a complex of conditions, $\mathscr T$, which allows
> of any number of repetitions" ... "We study a definite set of events
> which could be a result of the establishment of conditions $\mathscr T$

I'm assuming a *complex of conditions* is a logical expression $A$ that when true and events $B_n$ occur, forms an inference $\vdash A \implies B_0 \land .... \land B_n$ of which $P: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb R$ and $B_i \in \Omega$.  Repetitions are re-established by $\vdash \neg (B_0\land ...\land B_n) \land \neg A$.  I think the experimental data could also be a function $e: \mathbb N \rightarrow \mathscr P(\Omega)$. **Does anyone know if this interpretation is correct?**

This also seems to suggest multiple elementary events $\epsilon$ from the sample space $\Omega$ can be the result of a single experiment.  I was under assumption each experiment only resulted in a single event.  **Does anyone know which interpretation is correct**?

Comment: I think Kolmogorov was just trying to talk to his peers as probability at the time was considered to be like a physical process (like actual particles type of process) and he has just stating that probability theory is thinking in a repetition of an experiment that need not be based on any physical reality.

Comment: Thanks, I'm also trying to understand the logical and functional implications of the statement.

Comment: I don't think there are any. But if you find some, tag me in the comments.